# how to have 2 angular apps in yeoman and grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, angular-fullstack

I want to make another app in the yeoman using angular fullstack, how can I make it and keep it separated from the first app ?

I have created new html file in the client/app and a new application js also ... but this app is not downloading

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What exactly do you try to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to implement Landing pages , but I don't want to use the index.html because it includes all the system directives and parts , so i tried to add new html and js files